# assign splited Array to String

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

I have multiple text box name is " hobies "

```
String[] outerArray=request.getParameterValues("hobies");
    for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
           String[] innerArray=outerArray[i].split(",");
           String str = Arrays.toString(innerArray);
           System.out.println(str);
    }
```

I want to assign to string like

```
 String All = "Swiming,Reading,Singing";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: have you ever tried overriding of toString() ?
it is printing the weired things right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the brackets `[` and `]` with empty string:

```
String all = Arrays.toString(outerArray)
                   .replace("[", "")
                   .replace("]", "")
                   .replace(", ", ",");
System.out.println(all);//Swiming,Reading,Singing
```

Alternative way is using JDK8 [String::join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

> Returns a new String composed of copies of the CharSequence elements joined together with a copy of the specified delimiter.

Comment: It works, but why is there space after ( , ) like (swiming, reading)

Comment: Thanks for your kind hearted

Answer (score 0):

```
String All = "";
String[] outerArray=request.getParameterValues("hobies");
    for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
           String[] innerArray=outerArray[i].split(",");
           String str = Arrays.toString(innerArray);
           System.out.println(str);
           All+=str;
    } 
System.out.println(All);
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` and append it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.join(delimiter, elements)` function. This avoids the `[]`

```
String joinedString = String.join(",", array);
```